# How can I make different React components display 'inline'?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have different React components I would like to display all in the same line, like in a sentence.
The problem now is that there is a break before and after the components.
(The components `<RegisterModal/>` and `<LoginModal/>` elements are just words that trigger a popup.)

My React code...

```
<ToastBody className="logInline">
  Please <RegisterModal/> or <LoginModal/> to Upload
</ToastBody>
```

The CSS...

```
.logInline {
  display: inline;
  float:left;
}
```

The result...

[image]

The desired result (shopped)...

[image]

`display: flex` almost gets it done, but it is wonky with the heights.

[image]

Comment: Could you add the rendered html output?

Comment: You need to show the render methods of `RegisterModal` and `LoginModal`. The `display: inline` CSS should be applied to those elements, not the parent.

Comment: `display: inline` on the components 'register' and 'login' alone doesn't work.

Comment: Well show what they contain then! The most likely problem is that they render a block element (<div> or similar) and the solution would be to use a <span> instead, or target them with CSS. Any particular reason why you refuse to show their code or even rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.logInline {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It will move children in a row and align them vertically in center. Explicitly add spaces if you need them by either using `{' '}` or `&nbsp;`

Comment: 47 seconds too late :D

Comment: still down voted :( even though the solution works fine.

Comment: that wasn't me, my flex solution was also downvoted

Comment: I know, I didn't say that it was you. Anyway no worries.

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood :)

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything. I asked the question.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood my comment as I didn't blame anyone over it, I only said that it's been downvoted.

Comment: I edited my answer to show `flex` almost gets the job done, but not quite.

Comment: use it with `align-items: center`.

Answer (score 1):

cant know for sure because we dont have the full code but if you change your css to this it will probably resolve your problem

```
.logInline {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to show `flex` almost gets the job done, but not quite.

Comment: your register and login element probably have padding or margin but we cant know for sure without the full source

Comment: 'register' and 'login' don't belong to any class.

Comment: Well like I said i cant see whats going on without the rendered html code of the elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `display: inline` CSS to the components you want inline.

```
<ToastBody>
  Please <RegisterModal className="logInline"/> 
    or <LoginModal className="logInline"/> to Upload
</ToastBody>
```